# A python program for file download. But only data in last packet is written

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

everyone. I write a server program and a client program and client is designed to download file from the server. The following is a part of client program:

```
if Type == DS.CONTROL_IDX:
        if data["Success"] == True:
            stream = ""
            package = data["Package"]
            file_name = data["File_Name"]
            extension = data["Extend"]
            if extension == DS.TXT:
                fp = open(os.path.join(folder_root, file_name), 'w') 
                for i in range(package):
                    recv_msg = sock.recv(DS.FIXED_RECEIVE_LENGTH)
                    data = json.loads(recv_msg)
                    stream = stream + data["File"]

                pdb.set_trace() 
                write_len = fp.write(stream)
                fp.flush()
                os.fsync(fp.fileno())
                fp.close()    
        else:
            print("download fail")
```

In the server program, I have splitted the big file into packets which are padded to have the same size. In the *for* loop, data carried in each packet is appended to ***stream***, a string object. Finally, ***stream*** is written to the local file ***fp***. However, just shown in the picture [result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA7I3.png) and [result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOcQ6.png), only 1kb data is written. And 1kb is also the maxium size of data carried in one packet.

Could someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: `sock.recv(n)` will receive a maximum of `n` bytes, but could be less.

Comment: Hi,  Mark Tolonen. You are right. But now the problem is that the length of STREAM, a string object, shows all of bytes have been received, shown in picture 1. But  after file.write(STREAM), only 1kb is written successfully.  How weird!

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There are things that don't make sense in your code, like not opening the file in binary mode and using JSON to provide the data chunks.  JSON doesn't do binary without help.  There isn't enough info here to help.